# My question is about google custom search api and its "queries per 100 seconds per user" limit

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

We have an api key for the google custom search service. We are using the rest-api to list search results. We are now running a client script that needs to perform a lot of queries. If we run this script in one process the "queries per 100 seconds per user" is not exceeded, thats ok. But the time the script takes to query all the stuff it is too long. So we decided to split it into 4 processes and now, as you can guess, we reach the limit.

So, Here is my question...

What does "user" mean in the quota limit "queries per 100 seconds per user"? ... I can't figure out if "user" is "per project", "per api key", "per client ip", knowing what is the mean of "user" in the google custom search quota limit will help me to decide what can I do to resolve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API identifies users via the 'quotaUser' or 'userIP' parameters.  See https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage#limiting_requests_per_second_per_user